# Get weeknumber by date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have several dates in a spreadsheet:

[image]

I would like to get the weeknumber in the column `B` for the date in column `C` in european time.

I tried something like that(and also that above):

`= MID(TEXT(C2,"dd.m.yyyy"), 3, 2)`

However that only gives me `.2` in the `B` column...

Any suggestions on how to implement/start that?

I really appreciate your answer!

PS.: I also added `excel tags` because its similar to `google spreadsheet`. There is probably a chance that I can implement something from `excel` in `google spreadsheet`

Comment: U can use weeknum  --> like weeknum(c2) ..it will return 44

Comment: [Google spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3294949) as well as Excel has `WEEKNUM`, which should help.

Comment: Kare: there are numerous differences between Excel and Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in excel for get week number use

```
=WEEKNUM(C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula

```
WeekDay(c2)
```

It will return the week day number.